# Questions on hyperledger fabric MSP setting

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

### Background

I am studying the hyperledger fabic tutorial: [Building Your First Network (BYFN)](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html), and studying the details of the scripts. The source codes can be found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/first-network).

---

### Question

The command`byfn.sh generate` runs `cryptogen generate ./config=./crypto-config.yaml` and then generates certificates. A directory `crypto-config/` is produced with sub-directories `ordererOrganization/` and `peerOrganizations/`.

In the path `crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/`. It consists of

1. `ca/`
2. `msp/`
3. `peers`
4. `tlsca/`
5. `users/`

I have difficulties in understanding the structures in this directory.

**Q1:**  There are certs and private keys in `ca/`, `msp/` and `tlsa/`. But what are they representing? and why do we need them? It confuses me because inside directory of `peer/`, there are also `msp/` and `tls/`.

**Q2:** What is the purpose of `users/` directory? (I only know the network has peers and orderers). Are `user` and `admin` representing the end-users for this organization? and what is the difference between `user` and `admin`? Take this [network picture](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peers/peers.html#peers-and-organizations) for example, where are `user` and `admin`?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, public channel configuration is loaded only with what is found under `msp/`.
This is used to verify certificates of clients, and network nodes (peers, orderers).

The `ca/` folder just represents what a CA would have had it exited.
The `tlsca/` folder is basically used to define the same thing the `ca/` folder, only for TLS certificates. In fabric, there is a different certificate chain for TLS and for enrollment certificates.

Now, the `peers`, `orderers` , `users` contain the material for the local MSP of the node, as well as its signing identity (certificate, and private key).

The `user` is basically anyone that can authenticate to fabric as a client, and an admin is a special type of users who is authorized to sign transactions that have administrative changes on the organization it belongs to, like - adding anchor peers when sending a configuration transaction to the orderer, or - instantiating chaincode.

Comment: In terms of MSP Levels, can I say that `msp/`, `ca/`, and `tlsca/` belong to Network MSP and Channel MSP?. Is public channel joint by every peers in the network?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.... just ask in http://chat.hyperledger.org/ (you can ping me on there)