# Hyperledger Fabric cryptographic material confusion

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

### Background

I have some difficulties in understanding the generation of cryptographic materials in Hyperledger Fabric. I noticed there is a similar question, [Hyperledger fabric Crypto materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157865/hyperledger-fabric-crypto-materials), and I have asked this question [Questions on hyperledger fabric MSP setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384506/questions-on-hyperledger-fabric-msp-setting) before. but I still have lots of confusion.

I followed the example, [Building Your First Network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/build_network.html#crypto-generator), I noticed that using `cryptogen` tool and consume that `crypto-config.yaml`. It generates the keys and certs for the orderers and organizations.

For example, in the side the directory of  `crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/`, which has two peers and one user,
it has the following structure

```
|-- ca
|-- msp
|   |-- admincerts
|   |-- cacerts
|   `-- tlsacerts
|-- peers
|   |-- peer0.org1.example.com
|   |   |-- msp
|   |   |   |-- admincerts
|   |   |   |-- cacerts
|   |   |   |-- keystore
|   |   |   |-- signcerts
|   |   |   `-- tlscacerts
|   |   `-- tls
|   `-- peer1.org1.example.com
|       |-- msp
|       |   |-- admincerts
|       |   |-- cacerts
|       |   |-- keystore
|       |   |-- signcerts
|       |   `-- tlscacerts
|       `-- tls
|-- tlsca
|-- users
    |-- Admin@org1.example.com
    |   |-- msp
    |   |   |-- admincerts
    |   |   |-- cacerts
    |   |   |-- keystore
    |   |   |-- signcerts
    |   |   `-- tlscacerts
    |   `-- tls
    `-- User1@org1.example.com
        |-- msp
        |   |-- admincerts
        |   |-- cacerts
        |   |-- keystore
        |   |-- signcerts
        |   `-- tlscacerts
        `-- tls
```

### Below are my understanding and confusion that needs clarification

1. Files under `peers` are identities for that particular peer node (part of the blockchain network), while the files under `users` are the identities for the end user (i.e. clients?). Am I correct?
2. For the files under `peer#@org1.example.com`:

   - `keystore` (private key) is used to sign a transaction when the end user invoke a transaction (e.g. using the command `peer invoke ....`). Is the private key also used for endorsement?
   - `signcerts` (public key) is used to verify the endorsed transaction identity by orderers and committers. So, the public key shall distribute to all peers and orderers, but how?
   - What are the purpose of `admincerts`, `cacerts`, `tlscacerts`, and `tls`? And why `tls` is not under `msp`? Perhaps I do not have a good understanding of MSP
3. Similar to point 2 above, what is the purpose of keys and certs under `users`? Are they used only for logging in to the blockchain? Or would they be used for signing the transaction as well? and Perhaps use for accessing part of the blockchain (private data and access control?)
4. Moreover, I also noticed that `admincerts` under `peer0.org1.example.com`, `peer1.org1.example.com` and `Admin@org1.example.com` are the same. But they are different from the `admincerts` of `User1@org1.example.com`. That leads me to question why User1 needs the admincerts?
5. At the most upper layer (not beloging to `peers` and `users`), we still have three directories: `ca`, `msp`, and `tlsa`. What are their purpose? It seems that these keys and certs belong to no one. And `cryptogen` is said to have no CA, why there is still a `ca` here?

Thanks!

Comment: By continuing the BYFN tutorial, I realized that `tlsa` from orderer is required when running `peer Instantiate ...` ..etc. So my guess is `tlsa` is required for secure communication?

Comment: You can find your answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100493/7550476